# LIBGDX - group as child of an actor?

Tags: java, libgdx, oop, objects, hierarchy

I've looked in forums, the doc, and the code, and I'm thinking this isn't currently possible, but maybe I'm missing something, so just to be sure: is there a way to set a group as child of and actor? or, in other words, how do I create a hierarchy of actors?

I'm trying to make sorta of a strategic game, and I have things like "empires", "kingdoms", ""cities", "buildings", "people", "objects", and I thought initially that maybe would be a good idea make these things actors. But I can't find anything like addActor inside Actor class, or addGroup, it seems there is no way for "kingdoms" to have"cities", for "cities" to have "buildings", for actors to have child actors or child groups.

Comment: Why not just have the actors be `Group`s? Group extends from Actor so you will still have the same basic functionality.

Comment: You're right. I didn't think of that. I guess it sounds kind of weird, technically "buildings" are not a group of "persons", and a "person" is not a group of "items", but it can work anyway, so I'm going with this way. Thanks! And have a great year.

Answer (score 2):

We don't know which things are **containers** and what they can contain. 
But let's assume your world work this way:

1. **Empires** can contains **Kingdoms**, but also **Cities** (which are not contained by any Kingdom but belongs to an empire) and even **Buildings** following the same reasoning.
2. **Kingdoms** can contains **Cities** and **Buildings** (again, buildings which are not contained by any City but belongs to a Kingdom)
3. **Cities** can contains **Buildings**, **Peoples** and **Objects**

Now we've got something. Everything that can *contains one or more type of Actors* is a **Group**.

So you'll add to the stage a bunch of Groups (Empires in my exemple) containg themselves other groups (Empire is a Group containing other Groups like Kingdoms, themselves containing other groups and so on..)

Hope it helps.